# sourcetree - Where are all the remote repository paths store?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I want to delete some repositories to free up my disk space, but I want to backup the remote repository path for future use. I know that we can find the local repository's source path at: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\bookmarks.xml`, but I don't know sourcetree stores the remote repository path in which file.
[image: Source tree remote path]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those would be in your local `.git` directory which holds the repo configuration.

You can see it listed with `git remote show origin`.

Comment: You mean this file: `<Repo local path>\.git\config` ? (`.git` is the hidden folder)

Comment: In case hg repo, the file should be: `<Repo local path>\.hg\hgrc`